# Xpath Querying Multi-Attribute Selection

Tags: xml, xpath

My XML looks like this:

```
<device-attributes>
<devices>
<!--
    Devices
-->
    <device ipaddr="192.37.99.82" dtype="Linux" site="ELROND" node="ELROND-LC3">
        <Importance>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Importance>
        <Vulnerability>
            <Value>
                1
            </Value>
        </Vulnerability>
        <Properties>
            <ResolvedName>
                Fake.Domain.Title.com
            </ResolvedName>
        </Properties>
        <CMDB>
            <HPSM_CI_ID>
                CI146826
            </HPSM_CI_ID>
            <HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME>
                FakeName
            </HPSM_CI_COMMON_NAME>
        </CMDB>
    </device>
</devices>
```

This is a snippet (there are 500,000+ lines of similar data), but essentially what I am trying to do is grab the information in the device tag and the HPSM_CI_ID data.

For example:

192.37.99.82,Linux,ELROND,ELROND-LC3,CI146826

Here is my current XPath Query:

```
//devices/device[@ipaddr] | //HPSM_CI_ID
```

But this won't even return the IP that is in the Device Tag (trying to figure that part out so I can apply it to all portions of the tag).

Bonus question: Is there a way for XPath to split each result from the parent query?

For example:

192.168.0.1,Linux,ELROND,ELROND-LC3,CI41563 | 102.41.51.52,Windows,ELROND,ELROND-LC3,CI24783

This would make it a lot easier to parse the data but I can't figure out if this is even possible.

Comment: How are you using the xpath? Are you using XSLT to format your output?

Comment: I am not unfortunately, I have to run it on a middle-man software that just opens the file on the RAS server and runs the query. It returns everything in a comma delimited list, I wasn't sure if there was a way to tell XPath to delimit the end of a parent differently from a comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath is close but just needs a slight adjustment. Currently the `@ipaddr` is in your predicate which means you are actually looking at `device` that have an attribute of `@ipaddr` instead of finding the actual value of `@ipaddr`.

So the XPath to get that value would be this:

```
//devices/device/@ipaddr
```

However, if you are wanting every attribute you can change it to this:

```
//devices/device/@*
```

And then the XPath for your other element would be this:

```
//devices/device/CMDB/HPSM_CI_ID
```

Though if you are not getting the correct element from the application you are using you may want to try using the `@ipaddr` from your earlier search to get the correct one:

```
//devices/device[@ipaddr='192.37.99.82']/CMDB/HPSM_CI_ID
```

This would get you the specific `HPSM_CI_ID` for the `device` that matches that `ipaddr`

Comment: Thanks that works!

'//device/@*|//device/CMDB/HPSM_CI_ID'

However, do you have an answer to my second question? I can't figure out how to essentially have a delimiter when the query moves on to the next parent "device" tag. For example: IP1,CIID1 | IP2, CIID2 | IP3, CIID3

Comment: Are you able to use XPath functions? You can do `concat(xpath,'|')` which would put a pipe after your XPath result.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I will try this today and let you know!